# DateTime from unix timestamp is wrong

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

I have a string "2013-10-09 00:00:00" and I use the code below to change it to a timestamp

```
date_default_timezone_set($timeZone);
$timeStamp = strtotime("2013-10-09 00:00:00"); //echos 1381269600
```

When I do

```
date_default_timezone_set($timeZone);
date("Y-m-d H:m",$timeStamp);
```

I get 2013-10-09 00:**10**:00. This is completely strange. Why do I get this 10 minutes difference?

Comment: `date("Y-m-d H:m",$timeStamp);` minutes is `i` ;)

Comment: It's amazing how often this exact issue pops up here

Comment: That's how we roll :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you are using the `m` which is for the month not for the minute. You need to use `i`.

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Your code should be

```
date("Y-m-d H:i", $timeStamp);
```

Comment: Yup, that was pretty quick